# Do I need to glue 2x4 supports for an apron sink?

Tags: sink, cabinets, adhesive

I am replacing an undermount sink with an apron sink. I modified my cabinet and built a support for the apron sink, however I forgot to use glue on the 2X4's and just have them screwed together and to the cabinet vs using glue and screws. Is this OK or should I unscrew everything, add glue, and screw it back together? I am installing a Kholer 5826 sink if it matters.

Image of my supports: [image]

Comment: Apologies in advance, because you didn't ask, but plumbers take a pretty dim view of those accordian drain pipes. They gunk up something fierce, especially in a kitchen sink.

Comment: Yeah I am not too happy about that solution, the new sink will have a drain on the right side so for now that was the best option I could come up with without cutting out the current plumbing and redoing it. Have any other ideas?

Comment: Regarding the plumbing, it’s usually possible (though troublesome!) to get hard pipe to work. 22.5° couplers will be your friend. On another note, did you manage to get those upright 2x4s bearing on the actual floor, or are they just sitting on the bottom panel of the cab? They might be okay if they’re just in the cab, but the manufacturer specs say the bracing is supposed to hold 300 pounds. If you could pull the kick panel off the cab, you might be able to wedge a support between the floor and the underside of the cab bottom.

Comment: The 2X4s are on the bottom panel of the cabinet. I did consider cutting it out to get them to the floor but the bottom cabinet panel felt very sturdy so that seemed unnecessary to me. OK I found a 45 degree and 90 degree slip joint elbow at HD, I'm going to try that out, at least it won't have the wavy parts, but still a steep turn. Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Put in a 90 degree slip joint, looks muuuuch better now. We'll see how that steep of a turn holds up but so far so good.

Answer (score 3):

No. If anything you'd use construction adhesive, and not wood glue, but if you've done a good job with the screws glue isn't needed. In fact, it's rarely used in cases like this.

If you find that there's flex in your supports, re-screw it and make sure the boards are dead tight. Spread the screws widely in the vertical.